# Richfaces: rendered condition and bean with request scope

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

**Why my jsf does can not execute a action doAction1,my action showPanel set showPanel = true???,**

```
 <h:form>
   <h1> JSF do not post a "execute doAction1"</h1>
            <a4j:commandButton action="#{sample.showPanel}" value="Show Panel"
                reRender="MyPanelShow"></a4j:commandButton>

            <a4j:outputPanel id="MyPanelShow" >


                <rich:panel rendered="#{sample.showPanel}" id="panel1">
                    <h:inputText value="#{sample.name}" id="input1"></h:inputText>
                    <a4j:commandButton value="Ejecutar" action="#{sample.doAction1}"
                        reRender="MyPanelShow" id="action1"></a4j:commandButton>
                </rich:panel>


            </a4j:outputPanel>

        </h:form>

 <!-- Backing Bean-->

    package py.com.roshka.jrey.uifrw.web;

    import java.io.Serializable;

   public class SampleBean implements Serializable{
private String name;
private boolean showPanel = false;

public String doAction1() {

    name = name + " Ok";
    return null;
}

public String showPanel() {
    showPanel = true;
    return null;

}

/**
 * @return the name
 */
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

/**
 * @param name
 *            the name to set
 */
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

/**
 * @return the showPanel
 */
public boolean isShowPanel() {
    return showPanel;
}

/**
 * @param showPanel
 *            the showPanel to set
 */
public void setShowPanel(boolean showPanel) {
    this.showPanel = showPanel;
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure

```
rendered="#{sample.showPanel}"
```

evaluates to 'true' when you submit.

Comment: the first action "showPanel" set the showPanel=true.. but the request bean does not save the state of bean with the properties... how do i can set the current showPanel property when submit the second action???, are you some example...how  as it correctly? grateful a lot.

Comment: A request-scoped bean will hold a value for just one request. You need to use a longer scope such as session, view or something like a conversation.